# Capture webcam's image with Ruby

Tags: ruby, webcam

Is there any library in Ruby which I can use to capture the webcam's image? Has to run on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Using the `ruby-opencv` gem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39938093/407213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks good [http://www.wedesoft.demon.co.uk/hornetseye-api/files/HornetsEye-txt.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20070721072432/http://www.wedesoft.demon.co.uk/hornetseye-api/files/HornetsEye-txt.html) although I don't have any experience using it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at how it captures the webcam's image. Just in case anyone clicks your link, there's a missing "l". It's ".html" not ".htm".

Comment: Here is a snapchot of the project from 2010: https://web.archive.org/web/20100808100807/http://www.wedesoft.demon.co.uk/hornetseye-api/files/HornetsEye-txt.html

Comment: Using the OpenCV ruby gem is much simpler and works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39938093/407213