# Grabbing snapshots from webcams in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, webcam

How can I take snapshots from a webcam in ruby? I know the webcam device is on /dev/video0, but how do I get a picture from it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the developer of [Hornetseye](http://www.wedesoft.de/hornetseye-api/). You can capture images with the V4L2-interface of HornetsEye as follows.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'hornetseye_v4l2'
require 'hornetseye_xorg'
require 'hornetseye_rmagick'
include Hornetseye
input = V4L2Input.new '/dev/video0'
img = X11Display.show { input.read }
img.to_ubytergb.save_ubytergb 'test.png'
```

Currently supported colourspaces are UYVY, YUYV, YUV420, GREY, RGB24. Note that other colourspaces such as MJPEG are not supported at the moment.

Comment: The gem is [`hornetseye-v4l2`](https://rubygems.org/gems/hornetseye-v4l2)

Comment: But this doesn't work on macOS, and the OpenCV example works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39938139/407213

Comment: @Dorian yes, that's correct. It only works under GNU/Linux.

Comment: This is a very interesting project. When I see efforts like this, I wish ruby hype train was still running.

Comment: @nurettin Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've never actually used it but [hornetseye](https://www.wedesoft.de/hornetseye-api/) looks good. This question has also already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041882/capture-webcams-image-with-ruby/2042149#2042149)

Comment: I've been trying to use hornetseye, but it doesn't seem to fully work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Linux, try [videodog](http://freshmeat.net/projects/videodog/). It's a small program, which does one thing and does that well: capturing a frame from your /dev/video0 device. From that point you can use any Ruby technique you want to process the JPEG image you got from videodog.

Answer (score 0):

The [Video4Linux API](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Development:_Video4Linux_APIs) involves sending special [ioctl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl)s to the `/dev/video*` device, with data in packed structures; not something easy to do from Ruby.  (It's not all that much fun from C, either.)

> [ruby-v4l](http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-v4l/) is an extension library for capture pictures in Ruby using Video4Linux.

[Orphaned](http://bugs.debian.org/472721) in Debian because its maintainer hasn't been active since 2005, so if it doesn't work I don't think you'll be able to get much support.

A more modern solution would probably be to create proper [libv4l](http://hansdegoede.livejournal.com/3636.html) binding for Ruby.  However, I don't know of any present work on that.

Answer (score 0):

With the `ruby-opencv` gem:

```
require "opencv"

capture = OpenCV::CvCapture.open
sleep 1 # Warming up the webcam
capture.query.save("image.jpg")
capture.close
```

And to install OpenCV on macOS: `brew install homebrew/science/opencv --HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small wrapper-gem for the new OpenCV since ruby-opencv is stuck at OpenCV2, which isn't available on some modern systems. It should work on both macOS and Linux, provided OpenCV is installed.

Here it is: https://github.com/khasinski/framegrabber

In your case it would be:

```rb
Framegrabber.open(0) # 0 is the device id
image = Framegrabber.grab_image # Gets you a Magick::Image object
Framegrabber.release # turns off the webcam
```