# Detecting OS X camera with Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos

I'd know how to do this with AS3, but ruby search turns up nothing. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

[Capture webcam's image with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041882/capture-webcams-image-with-ruby)

http://www.wedesoft.demon.co.uk/hornetseye-api/files/HornetsEye-txt.html