# Opencv Ruby Highgui - build gem "manually"

Tags: ruby, opencv, highgui

I've followed all of the steps from this question: [Highgui and ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215736/highgui-and-ruby)

opencv was installed via brew, and rb_webcam was installed via gem install.

```
require "opencv"
require "rb_webcam"

capture = Webcam.new
```

The error is:

```
/Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nice-ffi-0.4/lib/nice-ffi/library.rb:98:in `load_library': Could not load highgui. (LoadError)
from /Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rb_webcam-0.3.0/lib/rb_webcam.rb:7:in `<module:Highgui>'
from /Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rb_webcam-0.3.0/lib/rb_webcam.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
from /Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
from /Users/swills/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
from gem_testing.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

In the other stackoverflow post from above, the the user made the post said that they-

"Solved it by downloading gem from here https://github.com/TyounanMOTI/rb_webcam and building and installing it manually."

My question is, how do I solve it by building and installing it manually?

(especially if 'gem install rb_webcam' isn't considered manual installation).